# codeigniter image path

Tags: image, codeigniter, path

I am a codeignite newbie and tried to add an image in my file under view folder.

I add  `<img src="../images/myImage.jpg"></img>` to my service_view.php. All I can see is a broken link of a small icon.

however, if I change my path to

```
<img src="../../user_guide/images/myImage.jpg"></img>
```

I can see the image.

My file system is as follow:

```
application-
   view ->folder    (where service_view.php is located)
   images -> folder   (where myImage.jpg is located)

user_guide- 
   images ->folder  ((where myImage.jpg is located))
```

Can anyone help me about this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest storing images in an `images` folder at the same level as the `application` folder, instead of trying to mix both PHP code and resources underneath `application`. Then just link to it like you did to the user guide:

```
<img src="../../images/myImage.jpg" />
```

Comment: I thought the best practice is to put images folder under the application folder. It also looks very odd to me that a simple path can't show the image.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the best practice?

Comment: no i don't, but i have seen few tutorials doing that way. Not sure what I should do now...

Comment: I have always done it the way I described, and stand by that answer.

Comment: Thanks Justin, so I guess we always create new folders (ex: css, images) outside of application folder?

Comment: @Jerry: Once you start using additional uri segments as controller function arguments, `../../relative/paths` become a bad idea (it won't find the image), use full paths or URLs. Justin is correct that common practice is to store static resources (images/css/js...) outside the application directory.

Comment: I think there could be major issues when refering to a image with relative paths, I recommend Do not use that

Comment: @decebal - Do you have a reference or a reason why relative paths are a bad idea?

Comment: @justin I'm not sure that this is the best example, but I often have troubles on using styles with image path relative if my url goes longer that the one the code is designer for, like an admin for a page(but there I may use another css), I promise to come back here and report if I remember

Answer (score 6):

I know more than year has passed since the question was asked but for anyone who comes looking in future, Here is my solution....

I've tried this created a folder images at same level as that of application, in main index.php added a line before last require_once statement.

```
define('IMAGE_PATH', APPPATH.'../images/');
```

and used IMAGE_PATH anywhere I wanted to display images.

Hope this helps

Comment: what if you want to use the image as a background in one of your styles sheets?

Answer (score 6):

I just have an image folder, 
domain.com/images

then on the views i just use /images

Answer (score 3):

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/image.png" />
```

and put the images folder outside of the application folder in the same directory

Comment: fine, when you use php as a template engine, try smarty or twig and it should be simpler

Answer (score 3):

Create an images folder at the same level of the applications folder.

With `base_url()` you can get the location of your site's base (cfr config).

This is useful because unlike site_url(), you can supply a string to a file, such as an image or stylesheet.
For example:

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url("/images/icons/stackOverflow.png"); ?>" alt="StackOverflow" title="StackOverflow is the best!" />
```

This would give you something like: `... src="http://example.com/images/icons/stackOverflow.png" ...`

Source: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Answer (score 0):

it is better practice to upload the images in a folder that is present in the root or the site folder and use base href in the first line of head tag. then the whole page does not need and http path reference. just use the relative path. as codeigniter run using the index.php file in the root, we should use all the relative path w.r.t that index.php page

Answer (score 0):

on local server try this

```
<img src="http://localhost/ci/uploads/<?php echo $this->upload->data()['file_name'];?>" width="200px"/>
```

on live use this

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url();?>/uploads/<?php echo $this->upload->data()['file_name'];?>" width="200px"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

put a folder on your root directory such as "assets/images/" and the in your code just use it as

`<img src="assets/images/imgname.jpg"></img>`

Answer (score 0):

Your file structure should be
-applications
-images
-assets
-Or any folder. 
Keep the application folder, images folder, and assets folder inside the basic root folder.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? How does this solve this more than six years old question that has an accepted answer?

Comment: Thank god someone replied, Am trying to say that keep the application folder, images folder, and assets folder inside the basic root folder. There a bit writing mistake.  Actually i have queation image in my project is displaying for firat time thats is for just as soon as i click on link it shows images but after for any buttons image isnot displaying, can you help please?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it as a new question. And if you made some mistake in your answer, please edit it

Answer (score 0):

Use when you want to include something from your root folder

FCPATH = C:\xampp\htdocs\your_root_folder\

```
<img src="<?php echo FCPATH; ?>/images/myImage.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

`<img src="<?php echo base_url('/assests/images/image_name.jpg')?>" alt="">`

This is the exact path for codeigniter, don't need write the "../../.." just write the path from assets (folder name)(sibling of application).
base_url gives the path of your project folder, not the path of the view folder inside application folder.